# Was the statement in Matthew 11:6 directed at John the Baptist?

Tags: matthew, gospels, christology, john-the-baptist

After receiving a disconcerting and disturbing inquiry from John's disciples concerning his identity,Christ tells John's disciples to go and report to John what they had seen.In his closing remarks Christ makes an interesting statement to John's disciples.

Matthew 11:6 NASB

> 6 And blessed is he [f]who does not [g]take offense at Me.”

Could this statement have been directed at John the Baptist?

Comment: In English it’s offense but in the Greek it’s more to do with stumbling over or beginning to doubt that He is the one who was to come. I’ve always read it as doubting so it will be interesting to see what responses you’ll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John was in a very disappointing and discouraging position.  He had given his every effort and to prepare the way for the Messiah and then, because of his integrity in the face of a dissolute and narcissistic Herod, was thrown into prison.

As far as we know, Jesus never visited John in prison and it is not hard to imagine how John could have begun to loose heart - was his life work all for nothing?

John sent some of his disciples to enquire of Jesus and Jesus replied as recorded in Matt 11:1-5.  Jesus concludes his reply message to John in the gentlest rebuke ever recorded - a blessing.  Ellicott expresses it this way:

> **Blessed is he**.--The words at once confirm the view that the question
>   which the messengers had brought came from the Baptist himself, and
>   show how tenderly our Lord dealt with the impatience which it implied.
>   A warning was needed, but it was given in the form of a beatitude
>   which it was still open to him to claim and make his own. Not to find
>   a stumbling-block in the manner in which the Christ had actually come,
>   that was the condition of entering fully into the blessedness of His
>   kingdom.

The Pulpit commentary is even more succinct and pointed:

> **And blessed is he, whosoever shall not be offended** (Matthew 5:29,
>   note) in me; shall find none occasion of stumbling in me (Revised
>   Version). But exhibits perfect trust under delay and disappointment
>   (James 1:12).